# Inverted video as a material

Tags: three.js

Assign the material from the video tag to the Mesh and get an inverted video. Before that, this place had a texture with the correct orientation. What can this be related to? I've have this problem when I switched from loading models in GLTF format

```
material = new MeshPhysicalMaterial();
const video = document.getElementById('myvideo');
video.play();
material.map = new VideoTexture(video);
material.map.format = RGBFormat;
```

http://prntscr.com/t4ldyf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your texture is showing up vertically inverted, you can flip it with the [`Texture.flipY`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/Texture.flipY) property. The default value is `true`, so try setting it to `false`.

```
material.map = new VideoTexture(video);
material.map.format = RGBFormat;
material.map.flipY = false;
```

Comment: Yesterday I solved my own problem in the same way :) Thanks for the answer!